# I store a JAVA date with UNIX timestamp in MongoDB and got a wrong answer

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I met a big problem that got my DB terrible when I store a UNIX timestamp into MongoDB.
Here's the code:

```
DBObject tmp = new BasicDBObject("_id", basicUrl+ob.getString("id"));//new a DBObject,it doesn't matter
 Date date= new Date(1316410912);//1316410912 is a UNIX timestamp
 tmp.put("created_at",date);
 mg = new Mongo();
 test=db.getCollection("qq");
 test.insert(tmp);
```

finish the add process,I print out the query result:

```
{ "_id" : "http://t.qq.com/p/t/163173122485971" , "created_at" : { "$date" : "1970-01-16T19:51:58.125Z"}}
```

but the real time should be "Mon Sep 19 2011 13:41:52"

please help me and tell me what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(date);` and see what's printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` takes time in milliseconds, not in seconds.

```
 Date date= new Date(1316410912000l);
```

That will produce correct date. See [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) for more details.

Comment: Shouldn't we just multiply by 1000 then?

Answer (score 1):

It should be in milliseconds, not in seconds.

```
Date(long date)
```

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the ms. Try

```
1316410912000l
```

This should bring you closer to the date you want.